# How to write a custom filter for ListView with Custom adapter that filter text at runtime and add that text to the top of list

Tags: android

I have a list view that is getting data from server each after 3 seconds new data is adding to the list view.my list view is working fine.For this list view i wrote a custom adapter each row contains some text values and button.I want if any text value is chat request then that row will be first row of the list view.

How can i filter text values at run time so that any row got value chat request then that row should add in list view firstly.

Can anyone help me?

i have not used the edit text for searching i want to implement a method that search for list view row text value and automatically added to the top of list without user intervention.

Can anyone help me for solving out my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this UI Pattern, that's very cool :)
I think it's write for you : https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

Comment: I am unable to import, kindly help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement much suits to this example "[Custom List Search Items](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items)".
Make Changes to the ArrayList items and call

> listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

will reflect the filtered items in the listview

Comment: But i have not used the edit text for searching i want to implement a method that search for list view row text value and automatically added to the top of list without user intervention.